# Gitlab Pages access with curl or postman

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I've created a gitlab page for myself and now want to access the page via a curl or a postman request. Seems that I can but the only way I can do this is by setting the Pages variable to `Everyone`[image]. The issue being it will be accessible without any access token.
I've been through gitlab's docs and couldn't find anything about setting it to `Only Project Members` and passing an access token so we can still access the page without having to logging into Gitlab

Does anyone know if there's any way this can be done?

Comment: Just to add, when it is set to `Only Project Members` and try to accesss via a curl it would return a 503 with a gitlab redirect html page

Comment: You want to read this chapter of the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html